# What does $[a + b]_+$ mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following equation, what does $[r_0 + s]_+$ mean?

[image: ?]

thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Please tell us where this equation comes from, so we have a clue what you're talking about.

Comment: It may mean positive part of an expression. i.e $[x]_{+} = \begin{cases}x, & x \ge 0\\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Comment: I've seen this defined as $[x]_+ := \max\{x, 0\}$, but this may not be standard notation. Ultimately you have to check with the paper/book where you found this.

Comment: I have taken this equation from a task for the subject "theoretical neuroscience" in university. The equation is presented after the first sentence: "The firing rate is determined in terms of a stimulus s(t) by integretating the equation:". After that the first task is to integrate (approximate) the equation by using the Euler method. @TonyK

Comment: If this task was given to you, but no explanation of the notation was previously given, then you should ask the instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, this subscript is a short form for the positive part of a number, $u_+=(u)_+=\max(0,u)$.